# How to do live debugging of ARM64 binaries on macOS with M1/M2 chips?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, arm64, macos

I'm trying to figure out why [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel?language=objc) fails in my SwiftUI app. I tried every possible documentation, or asking on the Swift programming forums - to no avail.

I'm originally a Windows programmer, and I am also a reverse engineer. The way I can see why some API doesn't work (on Windows) is usually by stepping into it with a live debugger/disassembler. This is what I want to do with the `NSSavePanel.runModal()` call. But I'm kinda new to macOS.

So to test the concept, I built a simple C++ app with the Xcode (natively for ARM64 architecture, with the "release" configuration):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if(argc > 2)
    {
        int a = atoi(argv[1]);
        int b = atoi(argv[2]);
        int c = a / b;
        
        printf("v=%d\n", c);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I then configured Xcode to "Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always show disassembly" and set a bp at the start. So I get this:

[image]

I can somewhat step-over and -into ARM64 assembly instructions with ^F6 and ^F7 keyboard shortcuts, but the Xcode UI is not really showing values of registers (one needs to type `p $register` into the console) and to see memory one needs to use "Debug -> Debug Workflow -> View memory" option, which is very clunky.

In other words, Xcode is not the best for this type of low-level debugging.

So I'm wondering, if there's another live debugger/disassembler that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/) is a free disassembler/decompiler that comes with a debugger

Comment: @mimak oh wow, it has a debugger now?

Comment: yes, apparently it was introduced in v10.0